# AJAX isn't working in Grails

Tags: html, ajax, grails

I have a GSP with the following code:

```
<head>
  <g:javascript library="jQuery"/>
</head>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <g:remoteLink action="ajaxRandom" update="quote">Next Quote</g:remoteLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <g:link action="list">Admin</g:link>
  </li>
</ul>

<body>
<div id="quote">
  <q>${quote.content}</q>
  <p>${quote.author}</p>
</div>

</body>
```

and a controller with

```
package grails_qotd

class QuoteController {

def scaffold = true

def quoteService

def random = {
    def randomQuote = quoteService.getRandomQuote()
    [quote : randomQuote]
}

def ajaxRandom = {
    def randomQuote = quoteService.getRandomQuote()
    render "<q>${randomQuote.content}</q><p>${randomQuote.author}</p>"
}
}
```

According to the Grails information (version 2.1.2), I have jQuery 1.8.0 installed as a plugin.

The problem is that when I click on 'Next Quote', a completely new page appears with the returned text, i.e. it is not inserted into the 'quote' DIV.

I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following needs to be added to the layout GSP:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
<r:layoutResources />
```

Comment: You don't need the plugin attribute. In your example you had `library="jQuery"`. It should be, as you have here `library="jquery"`.